# Importing math and TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, math

```
import math as m

def get_distance(latx,lonx,latp,lonp):
    '''
    Calculate the angular distance from point, x, to pole, p.
    Inputs and outputs should be in radians.
    '''
    # YOUR CODE HERE

    angular_distance = m.cos[m.sin(latx)*m.sin(latp)+m.cos(latx)*m.cos(latp)*m.cos(lonp-lonx)]
    print(angular_distance)
    raise NotImplementedError()

get_distance(48,50,87,22)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\13609\Documents\Search\dg.py", line 14, in <module>
    get_distance(48,50,87,22)
  File "C:\Users\13609\Documents\Search\dg.py", line 10, in get_distance
    angular_distance = m.cos[m.sin(latx)*m.sin(latp)+m.cos(latx)*m.cos(latp)*m.cos(lonp-lonx)]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `m.cos` is a *function*, you want to *call* it (`()`) not index into it (`[]`).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use parentheses when you call m.cos.
Your method call should be like this:

```
m.cos(m.sin(latx)*m.sin(latp)+m.cos(latx)*m.cos(latp)*m.cos(lonp-lonx))
```